# appendgrid data not populated as response, instead empty rows coming in the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Sometimes my appendgrid plugin not populating proper data instead same no empty rows are inserted as response array length.

```
var inputStr = '{"ok":true,"data":{"IssueDetails":[{"Name":"test121","Description":"test131666"}],"StatusDetails":{"L1_Process_ID":"1.0.0","WeeklyStatusText":"test blue1","NextWeekActivity":"p test"},"accessDetails":{"edit":true,"delete":false,"role":""}},"message":"Data retrieved successfully"}';
var responseData = JSON.parse(inputStr);

$('#tblStatusGrid').appendGrid({
        caption: 'Key Issues, Key Decisions, Key OCM Impacts (Including FTE +/-), Business Improvements',
        columns: [{
            name: 'Name',
            display: 'Name',
            type: 'text',
            displayCss: {
                width: '100px',
                height: 'auto'
            },
            ctrlAttr: {
                maxlength: 50
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Description',
            display: 'Description',
            type: 'textarea',
            displayCss: {
                width: '98%',
                height: 'auto'
            },

        }],
        hideButtons: {
            removeLast: true
        },
        //maxBodyHeight: 300,
       // maintainScroll: true
    });

    $('#tblStatusGrid').appendGrid('load', responseData.data.IssueDetails);
```

Here in the grid I should get a row of data as in response, but I am getting an empty instead. So please suggest a solution or any reason why so.

```
response : '{"ok":true,"data":{"IssueDetails":[{"Name":"PTP","Description":"DESC build"},{"Name":"PTP2","Description":"Desc Build2"},{"Name":"PTP","Description":"Desc Build33"}],"accessDetails":{"edit":true,"delete":false,"role":""}},"message":"Data retrieved successfully"}'
```

[grid after load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qccXu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look appendgrid docs [here](https://appendgrid.apphb.com/Documentation#link-dataLoaded)

add dataLoaded method you your code and watch with console.

```
dataLoaded: function (caller, records) {
    onsole.log(record.length);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but the problem is different i am able to see the no of rows but empty.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the problem is bit different i am able to see the no of rows in the grid as in response but are empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question.

If the we are using multiple appendgrids in my case I had multiple tabs loading the data to appendgrids so there might be a conflict of elements. So better check for the conflicts or empty the data for the other appendgrid which is not shown and then load the new data.

Comment: Thanks for following up. If you think this answer is valuable for other people, please consider extending it a bit. If your case was very specific, you might alternatively delete your question.